# How can I encrypt or prevent access to a user's files to another user in the system?

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, encryption, repair

I need to take my macbook pro (MBP 15 mid 2015) to a mac repair shop for a screen replacement.

I don't want to leave my files exposed to another user in the system. I plan to create a second admin account so they can check whatever they need.

Is there any way to prevent access to all my files? Let's say everything under my home folder.

Last time I checked, the macos feature called "File Vault" didn't fit the use case since a second admin account would have access to the files.

It doesn't need to be efficient, I'll just encrypt this before leaving it at the repair shop and later remove it.

I want to avoid doing a full back, clean everything and then restore the backup, but I'm open to ideas.